# How to see how many approved and rejected edits I have?

Tags: support, edits

Is there any way to see how many times my suggested edits have been approved and how many times they've been rejected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stats are shown on every approved/rejected suggested edit you made. You can see a list of all your edits on [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) under Activity > all actions > suggestions, then you can click on "approved/rejected edit" to see the actual edit review:

> [image]
>
> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21268550)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find it in your activity tab then all actions then suggestions.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/10388629/sirgopythonjavacppruby-the-3rd?tab=activity&sort=suggestions